# How to install adsense plugin in Gitbook

Tags: gitbook

The documentation for gitbook says the following:

Once you find a plugin that you want to install, you need to add it to your book.json:

```
{
    "plugins": ["myPlugin", "anotherPlugin"]
}
```

You can also specify a specific version using: "myPlugin@0.3.1". By default GitBook will resolve the latest version of the plugin compatible with the current GitBook version.

However, I do not know where this file is (book.json)?

I can see no links to even add a file called this in the edit section or settings section. Please can someone explain to me how I get a plugin installed on my GitBooks, for example the **Adsense** plugin.

I want to know, how to get this installed and also how to add the code to display the add on the page.

Thank you

Comment: Can we still put adsense on gitbook?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to FILES at the top of the left sidebar and then right click to create `book.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the full GitHub url with version:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "myplugin@git+https://github.com/MyCompany/mygitbookplugin.git#1.0.0"
    ]
}
```

https://toolchain.gitbook.com/plugins/create.html