# How to add a pluggin to gitbook?

Tags: gitbook

I am a begginer but I am building a gitbook for a personnal project.

When you want to add a pluggin it is said that "Once you find a plugin that you want to install, you need to add it to your book.json:" [here](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook/blob/master/docs/plugins/README.md)

I found the pluggin I want but I cannot find where I should install it ? Where is that book.json "thing" ? Do I need to have a github account to be able to do that ?

Thanks a lot

I've looked arount there is no tutorial existing for that

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404297/how-to-install-adsense-plugin-in-gitbook) it is said that "Switch to FILES at the top of the left sidebar and then right click to create book.json" but i dont get it, in the files part I am asked to drop or select a file and when I right click it just shows the classic menu of a webpage right click

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd need to have some sort of git service/git host where you can store the source in which you can find the `book.json`. GitHub is one of them and you can easily integrate it with GitBook (hence the name **Git**Book).

Here is a link to the documentation explaining exactly how to set it up. Alternatively you can use GitLab or self-host (the other option) although GitHub should be the easiest to start with. And yes you need an account on there.

[Enabling GitHub Sync](https://docs.gitbook.com/getting-started/git-sync/enabling-github-sync)

[Enabling GitLab Sync](https://docs.gitbook.com/getting-started/git-sync/enabling-gitlab-sync)